# Dedication at the first page of a chapter

Tags: environments, chapters, chapter-page

Is there already an environment to insert a dedication statement at the first page of a chapter? (Like in the below image)

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `scrbook` this would be possible with `dictum` (as far as I know)

Comment: Package `quotchap` perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

The `epigraph` package or the `memoir` class both cater for this. I'm afraid that you will have to read the documentation to understand how to get good vertical spacing for your particular dedication text as the chapter title may need to be moved down to allow space for the dedication. An example is (less any typos):

```
\epigraphhead[70pt]{\epigraph{\textit{To John Doe...}}{\textit{2015}}}
\dropchapter{2in}
\chapter{one}
\undodrop
...
```

**EDIT** Unfortunately the example code above does include some typos. Here is a working MWE (unless I've added more typos):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\begin{document}
\dropchapter{2in}
\chapter{First} % must be immediately followed by \epigraphhead
\epigraphhead[70]{\epigraph{\textit{To John Doe ...}}{\textit{2015}}}
\undodrop
First sentence.
\end{document}
```

The `\epigrahhead` macro sets its argument (the `\epigraph`) a distance `70\unitlength` (`\unitlength` being typically set to`1pt`) below the page header. The `\dropchapter` macro lowers the chapter title by 2 inches to allow space for the epigraph and `\undodrop` cancels the drop for any later chapters. The `\epigraph` macro takes two arguments, the first being the epigraph (in your case the dedication) text and the second normally the author (in your case the date). The epigraph text and author are normally set in a roman font but in the example will be set in italics.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask if it would be possible to provide a minimal working example of your solution? I tried `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\begin{document}
\dropchapter{1in}
\epigraphhead[70pt]{\epigraph{\textit{To John Doe...}}{\textit{2015}}}
\chapter{one}
\undodrop
\end{document}` but it does not work.

Comment: See the edited answer above.

Comment: I confirm that it works now.